# Adding LI to top of UL (EJS , MONGO, Node[Express])

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, mongodb, ejs

**What i did** : I already know how to add an LI to UL , but it goes to the bottom .
**What am i trying to do** : Add an LI to the top, so when my div.todos-wrapper (which have y-oveflow: hidden) hides oveflow , it still able to see todos , which you added .

**For now they just hidden until you scroll.**

```
EJS code - https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3ryn.png
```

> For more screenshots or code examples , please comment .

Comment: better to fetch blogs data in DESC order and then fill in LI, it will automatically do what you want

Comment: what you mean under "DESC" order ?

Comment: descending order,  assume that you're getting result `[1,2,3]` , but if you fetch blog data as `[3,2,1]` as reverse order, then in your list the first item will be the latest like 1,2,3

Comment: Yep. It solved my problem . I'm new here ,so how to give a shoutout :D

Comment: Just upvote the comment, Thank you!

Comment: I guess you need to ANSWER , not to comment , for me to UPVOTE

Comment: don't worry mate for giving shoutout, right now focus on your learning.

Comment: Now Okay ?! I hope you'll learn much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the sort order of `blog` data to `descending`,
It'll give you the result as you expect in `li`.

For example, you're getting

`blogs = [1,2,3]`

change sort order and fetch it like

`blogs = [3,2,1]`